# How to calculate an expected value of maximum random variable function

Tags: probability

1. Let  $X \sim U(0,1)$
   $Y=\max(X,0.5)$
   $Z=\max(X-0.5,0)$
   $W=\max(0.5-X,0)$

ask how to calculate $E(Y)$, $E(Z)$, $E(W)$

Comment: Hint:  $$E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)f_X(x)\mathrm dx$$ where you have been told what $f_X(x)$ is.  **Sketch** the function $g(x) = \max(x,0.5)$ and the function $f_X(x)$, and then the function $g(x)f_X(x)$. Compute the integral above to get $E[Y] = E[\max(X,0.5)]$.  Lather, rinse, repeat for the functions $\max(X-0.5,0)$ and $\max(0.5-X,0)$.

Comment: @Dilip: +1 for *Lather, rinse, repeat*.

Comment: @Dilip Given that my probability exam just was over a few hours back, if not for your comment, I am a goner. I did not realise I had this tool at disposal!

Comment: @KannappanSampath I call this tool LOTUS (an initialism of [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)) which helps jog my memory just when I need it most....

Comment: @DilipSarwate Now I think I'll remember this rule better. Once again, Thank you for telling me!

Answer (score 4):

Written to elaborate the already explanatory comment of Dilip Sawarte

---

Let $X$ be a random variable uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. This means that $$g_X(x)=1 ~~\text{for}~~ x \in (0,1)$$

We are interested in the expectation of the random variable, $Y=\max\left(X,\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$.

> Now, note that $$\begin{align}\mathbb E(f(X))&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g_X(x) \rm{d}x\\&=\int_{0}^1f(x)\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^{\frac 1 2}\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm dx+\int_{\frac 1 2}^1x~~\rm dx\\&=\dfrac 1 4+\dfrac 1 2-\dfrac 1 8\\&=\dfrac 5 8\end{align}$$

Similarly other integrals can be evaluated.

I'll leave only the answers in case you needed to check:

For (b) $\dfrac{1}{8}$

For (c) $\dfrac{1}{8}$

As Dilip Sawarte points out, some graphs you'll find useful are:

**for (a):**

$\hspace{1 in}$ [image: Graph 1]

**for (b):**

$\hspace{1 in}$ [image]

**for (c):**

$\hspace{1 in}$ [image: Graph 3]

Note that the area of the shaded region is the expectation you're in need of!

Comment: Yes, true. I'll add that in. But, given that the OP is doing Continuous random variable, he should know integration as well!

Comment: @Dilip I added the graphs. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: @Dilip Thanks for the pointer. GeoGebra does not allow the change AFAIK, so I should probably change the previous terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the formula below with $T$ being the statement that $X>0.5$,

$$ \mathbb{E}(X)=P(T)\;\mathbb{E}(X \;|\; 
T)+P(\text{not } T)\; \mathbb{E}(X \;|\; \text{not }T).$$

For example, for the first case we have

$$\mathbb{E}(Y)=(1/2)\; (3/4)+(1/2)\; (1/2)=5/8.$$